# Query Wordpress for link text via myPHPadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I'm locked out of Wordpress install but I have access to the cPanel of this site.

I need to just remove some links that are pointing to another site that I'm trying to rank for in google's SERPs.

So I figured that maybe I can query the database for all instances of the referring link I need to remove, and remove them that way, instead of waiting 10 million years for the support team to get back to me.

My question is this:

**How would I search all the posts in a Wordpress database for a string or link, and then how would I delete them? I know close to *nothing* about SQL, so your help is really appreciated...**

Comment: You can access the database via PHPmyAdmin? There should be a table called wp_something_posts, right? what's the name of that table?

Comment: it's just wp_posts... there's nothing between it.

Comment: I'm thinking of using a search and replace sql script, normally used for migrating wordpress sites, although I'm a little scared to because I don't know how to fix it if I break something.

Comment: I usually do  export -> search/replace -> import, but you're right, you should be careful.

Comment: I backed up the database via export, although I don't know if, in the event I break something, I could wipe out that database and import the own I downloaded and have it work like before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend pulling an export of the database and searching that data that way. Be aware that some text editors might struggle opening files of more than a few megabytes.

Another way to do this if you have access to phpMyAdmin is to click on the database name and then click search. You can enter the link you are looking for and search all the tables that way.

Comment: I actually did use that search feature and the page just went blank. i don't know if it was search but it took a long while and nothing showed up. Although I can see for sure that there are links coming from this site.

Comment: is this a case where you think you've been hacked?

Comment: I ask because those links might not be in there. You might have code that generates them at the end of your PHP scripts.

Comment: I did a search and replace on that particular table and it worked. I figured I can just do the reverse to fix anything I might mess up. I replaced my target string with 'dead-link'.

Comment: Great. Hope you get it worked out. Not sure how much data you have, but you might want to export the whole thing to check ( or a few tables at a time ).

Comment: Crap, I just realized that I don't want to nuke the site's links. I have to selective for about 40 links. Also, what worked out for me is that I didn't click "replace" at the bottom of the page after submitting the search and replace so nothing changed anyway haha.